# Packaging a python script from another repository into flask

Tags: python

I was tasked with creating 2 repositories.. one has a simple python script

the other is a flask application which should use the first script and return the results in a json

so both projects look something like this

## main.py

```
import random


def isPrime(n):
    # Corner case
    if n <= 1:
        return False

    # check from 2 to n-1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

    return True


# Function to print primes
def printPrime(n):
    previous_primes_nb = []
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if isPrime(i):
            previous_primes_nb.append(i)
    return previous_primes_nb


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # randomized number
    n = random.randint(2, 100)
    # function calling
    previous_primes_list = printPrime(n)
    print(previous_primes_list)
```

## simpleflask.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8777)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by creating a python package for main.py, and import that into your flask app.

[Official doc on creating python packages.](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

[Good tutorial on creating a package for internal use.](https://changhsinlee.com/python-package/)

You can make that internal package available to the simpleflask.py making sure it's on the PythonPath envirnoment variable or you can use a tool like [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) to distribute the package.

Comment: i've packaged my application into a jfrog PyPi artifactory using setup.py and .pypirc how do i import it into flask?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jfrog but I guess it's some sort of package hosting platform? You need to [install the package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/) into environment the script is running in and you need to [import that module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) into your script. You should also have a read of [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), they're isolated environments you can run a project in so dependency between different projects on your system don't clash.